# cannot integrate little script inside django/python app... can you explain how urls.py works?

Tags: python, django

I'm not a programmer, but I've written few things in php/mysql. So I've grasp of programming, but I cannot understand logic of django apps... and python is so weirdly complicated! Please help me solve a little problem I'm having.

My script is simple, it displays random sentence. nothing fancy!

So I've:
**random-quotes.py** -->

```
import random

#Random
def random_quotes (request, template_name='header.html'):
    quotes = ["\"There are always two people in every picture: the photographer and the viewer.\"",
              "\"My portraits are more about me than they are about the people I photograph.\" <br><span class=\"author_span_style\">~ Richard Avedon</span>"]
    pick_quote = quotes[random.randint(0, len(quotes) - 1)]
    return render(request, template_name, {
                                           'random_quote': pick_quote,
                                           })
```

**header.html** -->

```
{{ random_quote }}
```

**urls.py -->**

```
url(r'^$', app.random-quotes.random_quotes, name='random_quotes'),
```

This url thingy is completely weird to me. I got the idea that it maps template call to the "action" file. But details and reasons just escape me!

Anyhow, I used url structure from existing django app, (where I'm integrating little script)

So, app.[random-quotes].{random_quotes}
[is file name] and {is function name}

app. I'm not sure but I guess refers to the sub folder within my django app. I guessed it would be app. as in urls.py I discovered reference to the files in that folder.

For some strange reason, script doesn't work, it doesn't display anything... so I'm guessing problem should be the first part r'^$' and the fact that I didn't specify url.

please help me understand this concept...

Comment: There's a perfectly good tutorial. Have you read it?

Comment: It's referring to a function in a Python module. You can't call a module random-quotes, because that means random (minus) quotes. If you've never used Python before, you might want to glance at a Python tutorial first - it's not complicated, but it is very different to PHP.

Comment: Thomas K
I removed - minus now I've randomquotes.py

and:  url(r'^$', app.randomquotes.random_quotes, name='random_quotes'),

still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) provides an excellent explanation of what is happening here.

In short, any URL that matches the regular expression in urls.py will be mapped to the specified function in views.py. views.py will execute any necessary logic, and will load a template (if specified).

Comment: hm, but I don't see views.py anywhere...

I thought it was like this template -> urls.py -> someaction.py

Comment: It will be created when you run `python manage.py startapp <your_app_name>`. Did you create your application using that method?

Comment: yes, I think so. In the steps I made, what am I missing to make it work?

Comment: p.s. I read that tutorial first, but it doesn't explain why my script doesn't work.

Comment: The views.py will reside in the application directory. Bear in mind the difference between your project and the applications it contains. Please look in the 'random_quotes' directory to see if the views.py file exists there ( you should also see __init.__.py, models.py, and tests.py). If you do not see the files there, rerun the app-creation command I mentioned above.

Comment: When you have successfully created the app, you can edit the views.py file according to the directions in part 3 of the tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/).

Comment: no, I think you misunderstood my issue.

I'm adding functionality to django app written by others. It's similar to forum.

under folder /views/ I've init.py and other files like command.py I thought this was refered to by "app" so I included my randomquote.py in this folder.

Than I referenced url inside urls.py in the main folder.

Comment: If views.py is missing, your app will not work. Your next step is to create it.